# AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: Task function must be specified Error in Gulp

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

I just started learning gulp and I get the error when I write the following code. What is the reason ?

```
const gulp = require('gulp');
const imagemin = require('gulp-imagemin');

gulp.task('deneme',()=>{
  console.log("calisiyor");
});

gulp.task('resimKucult', () => {
  gulp.src('./src/img/**/*')
  .pipe(imagemin())
  .pipe(gulp.dest('./img/')); 
});

gulp.task('default',['resimKucult','deneme']);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"gulp": "^4.0.0" to : "gulp": "^3.9.1"

problem solved.